# How do you cluster every n elements in an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example, if you are given an array containing 22 hashes, and you want to group every 4 hashes into a new array which is also under another array. the last 2 elements will be inside a separate array as well (for edge case)

I already know the ghetto way of doing this, but since Ruby is so elegant and all powerful, there must be a way (one liner or two) to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: We want to be helpful, but, for yourself too, please state the problem in terms of code. Provide the input and hint the desired output. Eg. what does it mean "which is also under another array"?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky is absolutely right. The more info you provide, the more people can help you. At minimum you should provide input and desired output. Answer to "what have you tried" also helps much (shows your effort).

Comment: "the more info you provide..." - on a second thought, you shouldn't provide *too much* information, or otherwise no one will read it (we have limited time). Often I see questions with pages and pages of ruby code, HTML markup and CSS rules. I just skip those. Sad but true. My ideal question contains small runnable code (a snippet that I can copy/paste/run and see the error myself)

Comment: By the way, you should accept helpful answers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I got carried away to implement my algorithm.

Comment: No worries, I thought maybe you don't know this rule, since this is your first question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
arr = (1..10).to_a

arr # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

arr.each_slice(4).to_a # => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

Comment: @NeverAgain Whenever you think you need to do something with a data structure in Ruby, check the enumerable documentation.

Comment: @Priti: yes, but mine has example, and I was faster. :P

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No need for that example,as doc has the better one.

Comment: @Priti: it raises helpfulness of the answer. For example, now you don't need to navigate to documentation, you can start using the method right away, because it should be clear how it works.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No who don't go to the doc and directly post such a simple question,for them we need to navigate them to the doc,so that they become habituate to search the doc, and get familiar with other methods too for future references. For this method,doc has enough clear examples, we also shouldn't put any answer for this,rather a link to doc is enough. If you really wish to teach him,try to teach by saying how to search doc first.

Comment: @Priti: "by saying how to search doc first" - I think they have this at "how to ask" page, which is shown before the very first question. Didn't help, as you see. :)

Comment: @Priti: think about visitors from Google. I am not happy when I land to SO from google search results and I have to navigate further. I want my answer here and now.

Comment: Google has tons of examples of this particular one! So its redundant,we rather close such posts without answering.

Comment: @Priti: I offer you a challenge. Can you provide rubydoc search query that will lead me to the method? Obviously, you can't use `each_slice` in the query.

Comment: WHAT?? I don't understand,what do you mean?

Comment: @Priti: imagine you're the OP, trying to solve your problem. How would you go about googling it up? What query would you use to find `each_slice` method?

Comment: okay! now your answer in this post, VERY GOOD! Now think yourself as `OP` what would you type in `GOOGLE`, which would led you to this answer.

Comment: What you are trying to say is meaning less, there is only 1% chance to that other would type `How do you cluster every n elements in an array in Ruby?` and will be landed to this answer, still I am saying what you did,tried to reinvent a wheel, that's it.

Comment: @Priti I did look at doc, tried searching for keyword but did not find it. and googled for hours and did not find answer. I also asked this kind of question to my supervisor but he could not answer that what the exact name of this method is. Out of frustration, I asked here. I'm not the one to be blamed to ask this question.

Comment: @NeverAgain How I [`found`](http://www.google.co.in/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=collection+slicing+ruby&oq=collection+slicing+ruby&gs_l=hp.3..33i29i30.1720.7562.0.7843.23.19.0.0.0.0.1650.8574.3-4j1j3j1j2j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.ajbMjpec59s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.bmk&fp=318f0a3bace0b899&biw=1301&bih=647) this one? from there a great place [`Here`](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/488750875/slice-your-arrays). I took only few seconds to reach this correct method, which Sergio repeated here.

Comment: @Priti because you have the prior knowledge that it's called each_slice, while I assume the term is cluster, and using the same way you google, I got nothing that's related to the method.